# Rsnapshot: using different intervals for different directories

Tags: backup, rsnapshot

Is it possible to backup two different directories using two different intervals using rsnapshot? For example, if I want to backup my /home directory every day, but my /archive directory once a month. Or is that kind of moot point since rsnapshot only saves hard links if no changes are made?

Answer (score 5):

I'd try to create different config files and then call `rsnapshot` separately for each directory, passing the respective config file with the `-c` option.

Comment: I think this is definitely the way to go. just make sure you use a different `snapshot_root` in each config file.